# Visual Studio 2015 and IIS Express-IIS creates duplicate website after error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I am having a weird error when it comes to one of my projects in visual studio. I can start to debug, but when I run into an error or Visual Studio needs time to create a data tip my IIS express instance is lost and it will create a duplicate. After this happens and I try to hit the page again my browser will try to connect but will never get a response. I have tried to stop debugging and then start back up, but the IIS instance persists and I get the same result, trying to connect but no response. Also all of my break points turn to the not able to hit symbol.The only way to get back to being able to debug is to close visual studio and open it back up again. I'm sorry I don't have anymore information, but it almost seems to happen randomly.

Thanks in advance

**Edit**
This is what the break point looks like after I have stopped and restarted debugging.
[image: breakpoint after I restart debugging]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up finding out the issue for anyone having the same problem. My initial question was not exactly what was happening. Whenever I stopped the IIS instance, the port that I was running the server on was being taken over by a Microsoft process. So when I hit run again my process was blocked and then showing the error above.

In order to fix this issue. I had to change the virtual directory for the project. You can do so by clicking in the web project and selecting properties. Pick Web on the left hand side and then change the url with to contain a different port and then click on create virtual directory.